# Scalaz ambiguous import error when working with Monad

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

I'am doing something like this

```
for {
  x <- MonadX
  y <- MonadY
} yield {
  (x, y)
}
```

`MonadX` and `MonadY` have the type `M[X]` and `M[Y]` and I provided an instance `implicit m: Monad[M]`

this is my import

```
import scalaz.Monad
import scalaz.std.list._
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

import scalaz.Scalaz.ToBindOps

import scalaz.Scalaz.ToApplyOps
```

My error is :

`[error]  both value optionInstance in trait OptionInstances of type => scalaz.Traverse[Option] with scalaz.MonadPlus[Option] with scalaz.Each[Option] with scalaz.Index[Option] with scalaz.Length[Option] with scalaz.Cozip[Option] with scalaz.Zip[Option] with scalaz.Unzip[Option] with scalaz.Align[Option] with scalaz.IsEmpty[Option] with scalaz.Cobind[Option] with scalaz.Optional[Option]{def point[A](a: => A): Some[A]; def cojoin[A](a: Option[A]): Option[Some[A]]}
[error]  and value listInstance in trait ListInstances of type => scalaz.Traverse[List] with scalaz.MonadPlus[List] with scalaz.Each[List] with scalaz.Index[List] with scalaz.Length[List] with scalaz.Zip[List] with scalaz.Unzip[List] with scalaz.Align[List] with scalaz.IsEmpty[List] with scalaz.Cobind[List]{def empty[A]: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type}
[error]  match expected type scalaz.Monad[M]`

The point is that I don't want to import scalaz._ and Scalaz._ because I don't want to slow down my IDE

Answer (score 0):

I think because you don't restrict the higher kind and you have those imports, the compiler tries to perform implicit resolution and in short it's telling you that both `List[_]` and `Option[_]` can match `M[X]`.

I think if you are to keep the same imports, you will need to provide some kind of type refinement for your higher kinds, or at least be more specific with your logic.

Something like this:

```
def test[M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X] : Monad]) = ...
def test[M[X] <: Option[X] : Monad]) = ...
```

But if you are using `traverse`, I'm going to guess you are really after `sequence`, which you can do for free, and use `sequenceU` to distinguish automatically.

```
List(monadY, monadX, ....).sequenceU
```